# Узнать высоту изображения по определенной ширине

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5

Знаем ширину и высоту изображения. Высота `50px`, ширина `232px`.

Необходимо растянуть изображение во всю ширину блока. Ширина блока `800px`.

Что за формула, которая покажет какая высота изображения стала при ширине `800px`

Comment: Пример - https://jsfiddle.net/dxka017w/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нам, нужно понять, на сколько увеличилась ширина. Т.е. `800 (конечная ширина) делим на 232 (начальная ширина) = во сколько раз нужно увеличить высоту`.

`(800 / 232) * 50` = высота